# Remove whole blacklisted words from a string

Tags: php, replace, cpu-word, blacklist, word-boundary

The problem with the code, below, is that it removes **characters** from the string rather than the **words**.

```
$str = "In a minute, remove all of the corks from these bottles in the cellar";

$useless_words = array("the", "of", "or", "in", "a");

$newstr = str_replace($useless_words, "", $str);
```

Output of above:

```
In mute, remove ll   cks from se bottles   cellr
```

I need the output to be:

```
minute, remove all corks from these bottles cellar
```

I'm assuming I can't use `str_replace()`. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will do the job:

```
$str = "The game start in a minute, remove all of the corks from these bottles in the cellar";
$useless_words = array("the", "of", "or", "in", "a");
$pattern = '/\h+(?:' . implode($useless_words, '|') . ')\b/i';
$newstr = preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
echo $newstr,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
The game start minute, remove all corks from these bottles cellar
```

**Explanation:**

The pattern looks like : `/\h+(?:the|of|or|in|a)\b/i`

```
/                   : regex delimiter
  \h+               : 1 or more horizontal spaces
  (?:               : start non capture group
    the|of|or|in|a  : alternatives for all the useless words
  )                 : end group
  \b                : word boundary, make sure we don't have a word character before
/i                  : regex delimiter, case insensitive
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$useless_words = array(" the ", " of ", " or ", " in ", " a ");
$str = "In a minute, remove all of the corks from these bottles in the 
cellar";

$newstr = str_replace($useless_words, " ", $str);

$trimmed_useless_words = array_map('trim',$useless_words);
$newstr2 = '';
foreach ($trimmed_useless_words as &$value) {
   if (strcmp($value, substr($newstr,0,strlen($value)))){
       $newstr2 = substr($newstr, strlen($value) );
       break;
   }
}
if ($newstr2 == ''){
    $newstr2 = $newstr; 
}
echo $newstr2;
```

Comment: This works for this particular string, but if a new string needs to be evaluated and the string starts with "the", then that word wouldn't be removed.  But this is helpful.

Comment: Updated answer to cover the first word in the string

Answer (score 0):

In additional to enforcing whole word matches with word boundaries, use a conditional expression to consume the leading or trailing whitespace characters (but not both!).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/F1skm))

```
$str = "The game start in a minute, remove all of the corks from these bottles in the cellar they're in";
$useless_words = ["the", "of", "or", "in", "a"];

var_dump(
    preg_replace('/(\s+)?\b(?:' . implode('|', $useless_words) . ')\b(?(1)|\s+)/i', '', $str)
);
```

Output:

```
string(69) "game start minute, remove all corks from these bottles cellar they're"
```

Notice that the leading `The` plus trailing space is removed, the final `in` and its leading space is removed, `all of the corks` became `all corks` which is separated by only one space.